# Reading into one struct overwrites another

Tags: go, struct

I have some issues with managing structs in Go. I have complex struct and two variables based on that struct - "previous" and "current". I'm trying to read data from tarfile, do some calculations and replace previous with current.
But at next iteration of reading when I read to current, it seems to me, a content of "previous" overwritten and both variables become the same.
Struct defined as follows:

```
type Mystruct struct {
    Data       [][]sql.NullString
    Rnames     []string
    Nsize      int
    Msize      int
    Namemaxlen map[string]int
    Valid      bool
    Err        error
}
```

Variables are not pointers. Copy performs as direct assignment: previous = current.

```
tr := tar.NewReader(f)
var prev, curr Mystruct

for {
    hdr, err := tr.Next()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    data := make([]byte, hdr.Size)
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(tr, data); err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    if err = json.Unmarshal(data, &curr); err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    if prev.Valid != true {
        prev = curr
        continue
    }

    // other computations here

    prev = curr
}
```

Where do I wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it ok if I before reading will initialize "current" with `current := Mystruct{}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your struct contains slices which are basically pointers to memory. Copying those pointers means that your copy points to the SAME memory as the original, thus they share the slice values. Changing one changes the other.

Here is [a small example](https://play.golang.org/p/cip2ACpR_F8) to illustrate the problem:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type s struct {
    a     int
    slice []int
}

func main() {
    // create the original thing
    prev := s{
        a:     5,
        slice: []int{1, 2, 3},
    }
    // copy the thing into cur
    cur := prev
    // now change cur, changing a will change only cur.a because integers are
    // really copied
    cur.a = 6
    // changing the copied slice will actually change the original as well 
    // because copying a slice basically copies the pointer to memory and the
    // copy points to the same underlying memory area as the original
    cur.slice[0] = 999
    // printing both, we can see that the int a was changed only in the copy but
    // the slice has changed in both variables, because it references the same
    // memory
    fmt.Println(prev)
    fmt.Println(cur)
}
```

Comment: thanks, you've confirmed my thougts, i suspected arrays and map but was not completely sure.